# I/O in prolog: Error: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated, no further information

Tags: prolog

So I'm working with I/O in prolog and I'm getting

```
Error: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

What puzzles me is why I'm not getting any information on what predicate is causing the issue.

(EDIT: In the image L2 is the name of the prolog-file shown to the left, [L2.pl] gives the same error.)

[image]

What the program should do:
The program is supposed to verify a temporal logic statement. It will read a file (Input) and from the file get: an adjacency list of how states are connected (T); another adjacency list of what formulas each state contains (L); a state (S) and a temporal logic formula (F). Then it should check if the formula F is true in state S.

Here's example of how the Input-file can look:

```
[[s0, [s0, s2, s1]],
 [s1, [s1, s0]],
 [s2, [s0, s2]]].

[[s0, [p, q]],
 [s1, [p]],
 [s2, [q, r]]].

s0.

p
```

Right now I've only implemented a trivial check to see if formula F is in state S. But the program don't want to compile and I don't understand why.

Comment: I don't see how you're calling your predicate. The inset just shows you entering `[L2].` which isn't a query. What that syntax does is tells prolog to "consult" a file given by the variable `L2`. But `L2` isn't set to anything (it's not instantiated), so you get an instantiation error.

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry, L2 is the name of the prolog file. I'll add it. [L2.pl] gives the same error

Comment: Thank you so much! Make an answer of it and I'll check it as solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prolog, if you enter an identifier that is capitalized, it's considered a variable, even if it's used in the query to load a file:

```
?- [L2].
```

This attempts to load (or consult) a file whose name is given by the variable, `L2`. Of course, `L2` is not instantiated in the above, so this will fail with an instantiation error. For the same reason, the following will also fail:

```
?- [L2.pl].
```

The consult `[...]` requires an *atom* for a file name. If you want an atom that starts with a capital letter, you need to use quotes. So the following will work:

```
?- ['L2'].
```

Or

```
?- ['L2.pl'].
```